# Is $\mathbb{E}[X|F]\leq \mathbb{E} [X |\mathcal{E}]\frac{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})}{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})}$ true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, conditional-expectation

> Assume two event $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathcal{F}\subset \mathcal{E}$. Is this always true:
>   $$\mathbb{E}[X|F]\leq \mathbb{E} [X |\mathcal{E}]\frac{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})}{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})}$$?

**My answer:** Yes, because:

\begin{align}
\nonumber \mathbb{E} [X |\mathcal{F}]
\nonumber &= \frac{\mathbb{E} \left[X \mathbf{1}_\mathcal{F}\right]}{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})}\\
\nonumber &\leq  \frac{\mathbb{E} \left[X\mathbf{1}_\mathcal{E}\right]}{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})}\\
\nonumber &=  \frac{\mathbb{E} \left[X\mathbf{1}_\mathcal{E}\right]}{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})}\frac{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})}{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})}\\
\nonumber &= \mathbb{E} [X |\mathcal{E}]\frac{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})}{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})}\\
\end{align}

Is that correct? Is this a property?

Comment: How did you conclude that $\mathbb{E}[X1_F]\leq \mathbb{E}[X1_E]$?

Comment: @carmichael561 That is true since $\mathcal{F}\subset \mathcal{E}$

Comment: @Su20200 and what if e.g. $X$ is negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false.

Let $Y=-X$. Then if

$$\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal F]\leq \mathbb{E} [X |\mathcal{E}]\frac{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})}{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})}$$

we must have

$$\mathbb{E}[Y|\mathcal F]\geq \mathbb{E} [Y |\mathcal{E}]\frac{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})}{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})}$$

which is a counterexample.

However if $X$ is restricted to be positive then the statement is true, and your proof is valid. (As [carmichael561](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/314708/carmichael561) points out, the invalid step is to assume $\mathbb{E}[X1_\mathcal F]\leq\mathbb{E}[X1_\mathcal E]$. But this step is valid so long as $X$ is always nonnegative.)

Comment: Thanks. Is this a property?

Comment: @Su20200 What do you mean by "property"?

Comment: I mean a popular property of conditional expectation, etc.

Comment: @Su20200 Not as far as I know. But it is similar to [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality).